# Is there an Approximate tangent space that is NOT a Classical tangent space?

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, tangent-spaces, hausdorff-measure

First given $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $r>0$, we define the **blow up** by:
$$ \Phi_{x,r}(y) = \frac{y-x}{r}.$$

We say $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ has a $k$ dimensional approximate tangent space $\pi_x$ if

$$ H^k \llcorner \Big(\Phi_{x,r}(M) \Big) = H^k \llcorner \Big(\frac{M-x}{r} \Big) \text{ converges weakly to } H^k \llcorner \pi_x,$$

in other words,

$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{r^k} \int_M \varphi \Big( \frac{y-x}{r} \Big) dH^k(y) = \int_{\pi_x} \varphi dH^k $$

for all $\varphi \in C^0_c(\mathbb{R}^n).$

Now, there is a Theorem that says rectifiable sets have approximate tangent spaces $H^k$ a.e., and where they exist they are in fact classical tangent spaces.

My question is can we find a set $E$ and a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ not necessarily in $E$, such that an approximate tangent space $\pi_x$ exists but a classical tangent space does not?

We will need to consider "unrectifiable sets" due to the theorem.

A set that comes to mind is the purely unrectifiable cantor-like set $C \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ which we define inductively (paraphrased from Leon Simon), for $n = 0, 1, ...$ by:

$C_n$ is the union of $4^n$ squares each with length $4^{-n}$, and $C_{n+1}$ is obtained from $C_n$ by replacing each square *s* of $C_n$ with $4$ squares of edges length $4^{-n-1}$ each sharing a corner with *s*, then $C_{n+1} \subset C_n$. Then let $C = \cap_{n=1}^\infty C_n$.

I dont see if or how I can make this example work, but my question stands for maybe some other set.